how to debug FiveM LuA Language with executable file FiveM.exe on Vscode
When I add a feature or debug, I have to start or run the game repeatedly and do debug prints, which is very inefficient. However, if I could run it with VSCode debug, it might make it easier and even more efficient for me.
I want to create a launch.json in VSCode to start the server along with debugging in Lua programming language. So, I can set breakpoints to stop the code inside a class without having to do debug prints.

When developing your own server, you can simply save the file you're editing, then in the server console, execute the "refresh" command and then "ensure [name of the resource]". This will update the scripts without having to restart the server and the client !
